# How do I print all filtered elements in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, filter, printing, pymongo

I'm pretty new to programming and am trying to filter my MongoDB to then print out every found element.

when picking out one element, this does not seem to be a problem.

```
c = db.get_collection("measurements")
print(c.find_one(filter={"source_id": ObjectId('5da20646b3f23b001054cf5a')}))
```

printing the whole element:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5da20651b3f23b001054cf5b'), 'version': 'c79a820', 'source_id': ObjectId('5da20646b3f23b001054cf5a'), 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 12, 16, 58, 48), 'location_information': {'latitude': 48.9989464, 'longitude': 12.1009412, 'accuracy': 15.557,
'altitude': 418.70001220703125, 'age': 74}, 'battery': 0.24, 'cell_info': [{'active': True, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'cell_id': '20724994', 'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 'location_area_code': '58612', 'mobile_country_code': '262', 'mobile_network_code': '3', 'physical_cell_id': '118'}, 
'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '24', 'channel_quality_indicator': '6', 'dbm': '-116', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-116', 'reference_signal_received_quality': '-13', 'reference_signal_signal_to_noise_ratio': '-2', 'timing_advance_radio': '8'}}, {'active': False, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 
'mobile_country_code': '2147483647', 'mobile_network_code': '2147483647', 'physical_cell_id': '445'}, 'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '19', 'dbm': '-121', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-121', 'reference_signal_received_quality': '-18', 'timing_advance_radio': '-1'}}, {'active': False, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 
'mobile_country_code': '2147483647', 'mobile_network_code': '2147483647', 'physical_cell_id': '129'}, 'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '18', 'dbm': '-122', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-122', 
'reference_signal_received_quality': '-19', 'timing_advance_radio': '-1'}}]}
```

Now I want to print every element that is equal/younger than today's date:

```
results = (c.find({'timestamp':{'$gt':'2020, 1, 1, 12, 25, 1'}}))

for x in results:
        pprint.pprint(x)
```

it does not print anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python drivers require you to convert your date/time query into a `datetime` instance to perform the required comparison on the `date (ISODate)` field in the collection.

So what you need is something like:

```
results = db.mycollection.find({'timestamp':{'$gt': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 12, 25, 1)}})
```

Full worked example:

```
import pymongo
import datetime
from bson import ObjectId

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mycollection']

db.mycollection.insert_one({'version': 'c79a820', 'source_id': ObjectId('5da20646b3f23b001054cf5a'), 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 12, 16, 58, 48), 'location_information': {'latitude': 48.9989464, 'longitude': 12.1009412, 'accuracy': 15.557, 'altitude': 418.70001220703125, 'age': 74}, 'battery': 0.24, 'cell_info': [{'active': True, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'cell_id': '20724994', 'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 'location_area_code': '58612', 'mobile_country_code': '262', 'mobile_network_code': '3', 'physical_cell_id': '118'}, 'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '24', 'channel_quality_indicator': '6', 'dbm': '-116', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-116', 'reference_signal_received_quality': '-13', 'reference_signal_signal_to_noise_ratio': '-2', 'timing_advance_radio': '8'}}, {'active': False, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 'mobile_country_code': '2147483647', 'mobile_network_code': '2147483647', 'physical_cell_id': '445'}, 'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '19', 'dbm': '-121', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-121', 'reference_signal_received_quality': '-18', 'timing_advance_radio': '-1'}}, {'active': False, 'type': 'LTE', 'cell_identity': {'e_utra_absolute_radio_frequency_channel_number': '6200', 'mobile_country_code': '2147483647', 'mobile_network_code': '2147483647', 'physical_cell_id': '129'}, 'cell_signal_strength': {'asu': '18', 'dbm': '-122', 'reference_signal_received_power': '-122', 'reference_signal_received_quality': '-19', 'timing_advance_radio': '-1'}}]})
results = db.mycollection.find({'timestamp':{'$gt': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 12, 25, 1)}})

for x in results:
    print(x)
```